# Bad Request on accessing Firebase dynamic-links using REST API (using JS)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, analytics, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm trying to implement a simple URL shortener using firebase dynamic links via the REST API.
I prepared a simple async JS function for testing (since I don't have a billing account to make external egress calls in cloud functions).
Below is the code:

```
async function fetcher(keyAPI,tempURL) {
        let reqURL=`https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=${keyAPI}`;
        let parameters = {
            method : "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body : JSON.stringify({
                "longDynamicLink": tempURL,
                 "suffix": {
                     "option": "SHORT"
                     }
                })
            };
            await fetch(reqURL,parameters)
            .then(res => console.log(res))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
```

I'm recieving a bad request as the response:

> Response {
>     type: "cors", "https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=[MY_WEB_API_KEY_HERE]",
>     redirected: true,
>     status: 400,
>     ok: false,
>     statusText: "Bad Request",
>     headers: Headers,
>     body: ReadableStream,
>     bodyUsed: false
>   }

I need help to debug it.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following after creating a prefix link URL in the firebase console since it is required as a parameter:

```
let reqURL=`https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=<API_KEY_HERE>`;
let parameters = {
    method : "POST",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body : JSON.stringify({                  
        "dynamicLinkInfo": {
            "domainUriPrefix": "[PREFIX_URL]",
            "link": "[YOUR_LINK]",
        },
        "suffix": {
                    "option": "SHORT"
            }
        })
    }; 

// Get response since it returns pending promise above
return await fetch(reqURL,parameters)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(err => err);

}

// Fetch from Promise
sURL.then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    return res;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

My previous answer was deleted, I don't know why, but its ok

[Deleted Post IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kCYx.png)

I faced this problem earlier and some research on it. And it was working. So I took my all code, cleaned it up, and published it on Github, so this doubt can go.

So, Some comments asked How to use this, So here is the answer

1. You have to add lib from the CDN or self host it, its better to customize the code by yourself for your needs. CDN Link - https://fdl.js.org/src/links.js
2. Now when you have added the lib, try to call it with this function.

   This returns you the shortlink

   `makefdl(key, st, si, sd, domain, link);`
   [Expression Docs](https://fdl.js.org)
3. And You get the shortlink back...

Note: You have to wait for the API to reply, so make a await call, like this

```js
async function links(){
    var slink = await makefdl(key, st, si, sd, domain, link);
    if(slink != null){
    console.log(slink);
    // do something here with the shortlink
    }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://fdl.js.org/src/links.js"></script>
```

If you have any questions then please write down in the comments. I will be happy to answer. :)

[For more info about FDljs, visit FDL.js Official Site](https://fdl.js.org)